# How to give c:if tag in display tag

Tags: jstl, displaytag

I have a display tag in my jsp file. Its like..

```
<display:table id="currentRow" name="${ListObj}" requestURI="" sort="page" defaultsort="2"
                    pagesize="5" class="displayTable">
            <display:caption><font color="red">Users List</font></display:caption>

            <display:column property="ID" title="Role" ></display:column>
            <display:column property="Name" title="User Name" sortable="true"></display:column>

            <c:if test="%{currentRow.ID ne '1'}">
                <display:column >
                    <a href="javascript:editUserJS('editUser.jav?id=${currentRow.ID}');"><i>edit</i></a>
                </display:column>

            </c:if> 

        </display:table>
```

i had wrote the code `<c:if test="%{currentRow.ID ne '1'}">` for that i didnt want to show the edit link for user with ID 1. But that condition is not working. Ie no rows in display tag shows edit link. But if i give `<c:if test="%{currentRow.ID eq '1'}">`, edit link will be displayed.

How can i make it displayed for all the rows except the one with ID=1???

Comment: Should the condition be `${currentRow.ID ne '1'} `or is it a typo ?

Comment: ya i want to check whether the ID has the value 1

Comment: If ${currentRow.ID eq '1'} works did you try `${not (currentRow.ID eq '1')}`?

Comment: its also not working dear. i ha tried it too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the if statement inside the `<display:column>` tag as you will always want the `<td>` tag rendered in the table even if it is empty.

```
<display:column >
    <c:if test="%{currentRow.ID ne 1}">
        <a href="javascript:editUserJS('editUser.jav?id=${currentRow.ID}');"><i>edit</i></a>
    </c:if>
</display:column>
```

If the id attribute is an integer you will want to perform equals on it as an int.

Comment: Thanks Krock.. it was rite.. And a special thanks for ur nice explanation.. +1